# 'foreach' and 'with' binding not working together

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to bind a list using `foreach`, and also bind dropdown or select element in a table. When a user clicks on a select element associated tax value bind to the tax field. I bind this field using `with` binding context but it's not working, so what is the problem in my code?

```js
function formatCurrency(value) {
    return "$" + value.toFixed(4);
}

function MEI(vm) {
    var self = this;
    self.Amount = ko.observable();
    self.RevenueDetails = ko.observableArray(vm.RevenueDetails());
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.RepCode = ko.observable();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new MEI(ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))));
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">TaxCode</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">Tax</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:RevenueDetails">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker"  data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" readonly>
            </td>   
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" data-bind='options:DefaultTaxCodes, optionsCaption: " -- ", optionsText: function (item) { return item.Tax }, optionsValue: function (item) { return item.TaxCodeId }, value:$parent.selectedItem'>
                </select>
            </td>                         
            <td data-bind="with:$parent.selectedItem">  
                <span data-bind="text:TaxRate" />                              
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  class="form-control"  />                             
            </td>   
          </tr>
    </tbody>         
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: You have `koobservable` (missing a dot).

Answer (score 0):

- Keep an eye on the quotes in your binding expression. In the sample in your question you have mixed up single and double quotes.
- Don't use the `optionsValue` binding when you want to save the actual item itself (a `RevenueDetails` object, in this case) to an observable (`$parent.selectedItem`, in this case)
- Avoid writing functions in the bindings. Use observables or computed values. If you need a function to calculate something, create it in the viewmodel, not in the view.
- `optionsText` expects a string (the name of a key from the objects in `options`)
- You don't have to write binding expressions on the same line. Format your source code for readability instead.

```html
<select class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: DefaultTaxCodes,
    optionsCaption: ' -- ',
    optionsText: 'Tax'
    value: $parent.selectedItem
">
```

Comment: The note about `optionsValue` is the key one.